# Entity Framework Dynamic Query Expression being ignored

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have an operation that takes a serializable QueryModel and converts it to an Expression to be passed to Entity Framework. My query against the database looks like:

```
    public IEnumerable<PhotoVerifySessionOverview> FindSessions(Expression<Func<vwPhotoVerifySession, bool>> predicate, PaginationModel model)
    {

        var sessions =  Context.vwPhotoVerifySessions
            .AsQueryable()
            .Where(predicate)
            .OrderBy(string.Format("{0} {1}", model.OrderByColumn, model.OrderByDirection))
            .Skip(model.Offset)
            .Take(model.PageSize);

        return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<PhotoVerifySessionOverview>>(sessions);
    }
```

and my predicate builder looks like:

```
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<vwPhotoVerifySession>();

        //Add the tenant to the where clause
        if (model.TenantId.HasValue)
            predicate.And(p => p.TenantId == model.TenantId.Value);
        else
            predicate.And(p => p.TenantReferenceId == model.TenantReferenceId);

        //Add a date range if one is present
        if (model.CreatedOnRange != default(DateRange))
        {
            var endDate = model.CreatedOnRange.End == default(DateTime) ? DateTime.Now : model.CreatedOnRange.End;

            predicate.And(p => p.CreatedOn >= model.CreatedOnRange.Start && p.CreatedOn <= endDate);
        }

        //Include status filtering if any filters are present
        if (model.StatusFilter != null && model.StatusFilter.Any())
        {
            //use Id and name to search for status
            predicate.And(p => model.StatusFilter.Any(f => f.StatusId == p.StatusId || p.Status == f.Name));
        }

        var pagination = model as PaginationModel;

        var sessions = Manager.FindSessions(predicate, pagination);

        return sessions;
```

The problem is, my Where clause is not being evaluated and all results are being returned. Is there something else I should be doing to get the Where statement to work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign `predicate` back to itself.

```
 predicate = predicate.And(p => p.TenantId == model.TenantId.Value);
```